# Problem with reinitializing of string in iPhone

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I have an interface like this:

```
@interface MacCalculatorAppDelegate:NSObject 
<UIApplicationDelegate> {

    // ...
    UIButton *operatorPressed;
    NSString *waitingOperation;

}
```

And I am initializing `waitingOperation` variable in my implementation like this:

```
- (id)init { 

    if (self = [super init]) {
        waitingOperation = @"not set";
    }

    return self;
}
```

And I want to reinitialize this variable in a function. This is calculator program and when user clicks on operators button the following function will be invoked:

```
- (IBAction)operatorPressed:(UIButton *)sender {

    if([@"+" isEqual:operand]) {
        waitingOperation = @"+";
    }
}
```

But after the check in `if` statement, my program won't do anything and this happens when I am trying to reinitialize `waitingOperation` variable.

I am new to `objective-c`, please help me understand what's wrong here.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are several things to note here.

```
waitingOperation=@"not set";
```

As it stands, this will eventually crash your program.  Objective C string literals are autoreleased instances of `NSString`, which means unless you assign it to a retained property or retain it manually, the memory will be deallocated, leaving a dangling pointer.

```
-(IBAction) operatorPressed:(UIButton *)sender {
```

Have you verified that this method is actually being called?  You have to assign the `IBAction` in Interface Builder.  Step through it in the debugger or use `NSLog` to verify that this method is being called.

```
if([@"+" isEqual:operand])
```

Where is `operand` coming from?

```
waitingOperation=@"+";
```

Same problem as above, this will get deallocated behind the scenes, leaving you with a dangling pointer.

Also, note that if you know that both variables are `NSString`s, using `isEqualToString:` is faster than using `isEqual:`.

Finally, this stuff shouldn't be part of your app delegate.  This is view controller logic.

Comment: my operand is like here.............  
 NSString *operand=[[sender titleLabel] text];
 resultDisplay.text=operand;

Comment: and yes compiler is coming inside this function and it is true my program is being crashed.Thanks for reply.please know me what is m getting wrong with this code

Comment: In your question you state that your program is not doing anything.  In this response you state that it is crashing.  Which is it?  Have you fixed the things I've pointed out?

Comment: hi Jim. sorry new in Ob-C. I added 
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString* waitingOperation;
in my interface but still program is being crashed please give me step info.

Comment: Are you assigning to the property or to the instance variable?  In other words - have you changed `waitingOperation` to `self.waitingOperation`?

Comment: yes i just did. Inside of Init function i wrote
 self.waitingOperation=@"not set";

Comment: And have you also changed it in the other places?  What error message to you get when it crashes?

Comment: ans also i modify function 
- (IBAction)operatorPressed:(UIButton *)sender {

    if([@"+" isEqual:operand]) {
        self.waitingOperation = @"+";
    }
}

Comment: but still program is being crashed.

Comment: I written "isEqualToString" instead of "isEqual".

Comment: Please post the crash message.

Comment: <quote>As it stands, this will eventually crash your program. Objective C string literals are autoreleased instances of NSString</quote> This is completely _false_. String literals are immortal; they're created at compile time and cannot be released.

Answer (score 0):

If your operand is also a string, then check for `isEqualToString` instead of `isEqual`

Comment: i did it but still my program is being crashed at the time of reinitialization of "waitingOperation".